# Run command remotely on Linux environment

Tags: linux

I've two Linux machines and I am writing a script in machine_1 which grep word from file on machine_2 and append it to file on machine_1.

I used **`expect`** package and I can authenticate machine_2 successfully.

Any ideas How to run script like this in background ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to remotely run a command and you have ssh pub/private key authentication set-up. you can use

```
ssh machine2 <command to be executed>
```

and to run a command in the background add ampersand at the end with an optional nohup.

```
nohup command &
```

Comment: there is password authentication, how can i pass this ? also how can i redirect results to file in machine_1

Comment: you need sshpass utility.
sshpass -fpasswordfile.txt ssh user@hostname. The stdout of the command will be on machine_1 only.